# How to add sub column headers and symbols in Struts2 jqueryGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

i have  requirement to implement a column in `Struts2-Jquery Grid` 
like bellow

```
------------------------------  
col1    |   col2 is main column
________|________________________
        |  Sub col1 | Sub col 2
________|___________|____________                 

   /* Data */ in rows format
```

I and I want to add `Tick` symbol in sub columns .. Can Any one please help me How to achieve this 
I am using `Struts2 Jquery grid`

The below is my JSP page Please tell me Where I am doing Mistake.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
 <html>
     <head>
       <sj:head jquerytheme="redmond" jqueryui="true" />
       <title>JSP Page</title>
       <script type="text/javascript">
    function doGridComplete()
    {
        $("#gridId").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', { useColSpanStyle: true, groupHeaders:[ {startColumnName: 'idcountry', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: '<em>col2 is main column</em>'}] }).trigger("reloadGrid");            
    } 


  </script>
    </head>
   <body>
   <s:form name="testform"  >

    <s:url id="topgrid" action="countrygrid"/>
    <s:url id="middlegrid" action="stategrid"/>
    <s:url id="bottomgrid" action="citygrid"/>

    <sjg:grid dataType="json" gridModel="gridModel" navigator="false"
              pager="true"
              viewrecords="true" width="600"
              href="%{topgrid}"
              height="400"
              id="gridId"
                >

        <sjg:gridColumn name="idcountry" title="Country Id" labelSeparator="jak" label="HI this is lable">
        </sjg:gridColumn>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="countryname"  disabled="true" title="Country Name" key="true" align="center"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="countryname" title="Country Name" key="true" align="center"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="countryname" title="Country Name" key="true" align="center"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="countryname" title="Country Name" key="true" align="center"/>

    </sjg:grid>
    <script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>

    function doGridComplete()
    {
        $("#gridId").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', { useColSpanStyle: true, groupHeaders:[ {startColumnName: 'idcountry', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: '<em>col2 is main column</em>'}] }).trigger("reloadGrid");            
    } 
    doGridComplete();

   </script>
            </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: My Grid Output When I do click on column headers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `doGridComplete()` after your grid.

```
<sjg:grid dataType="json" gridModel="gridModel" navigator="false"
          pager="true"
          viewrecords="true" width="600"
          href="%{topgrid}"
          height="400"
          id="gridId" 
          onGridCompleteTopics="gridcomplete">

    <sjg:gridColumn name="idcountry" title="Country Id" labelSeparator="jak" label="HI this is lable">
    </sjg:gridColumn>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="countryname" title="Country Name" key="true" align="center"/>
</sjg:grid>

<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>

        function doGridComplete()
        {
             $("#gridId").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', { useColSpanStyle: true, groupHeaders:[ {startColumnName: 'sub_Col1_name', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: '<em>col2 is main column</em>'}] });            
        } 
        doGridComplete();

</script>
```

`sub_Col1_name` in `startColumnName` is the name of column that you want to start the header grouping from. Hope this helps.

Comment: @looser What version of `struts2-jqGrid` are you using?

Comment: @looser You don't have `idstate` in the code that you posted but you used it in the `doGridComplete` function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45975/discussion-between-uchenna-nwanyanwu-and-looser)

Comment: @looser 
Wow
that's nice to hear
You can upvote and select the answer

Comment: Hey .. Thats giving some unexpected behaviour when I click On column headers .. I did edit my question with the screen shot .

Comment: @looser The unexpected behavior your are talking about, Is it the 7 rows of `col2 is main column` on the screen shot or any other event resulting from clicking the column header. Can you describe the issue appropriately?

Comment: Sorry for lame explanation ... When I click on column headers .. one more column header name is adding `col2 is main column`

Comment: No luck .. Its still same problem

Comment: @looser Can you just call the function `doGridComplete` after the grid. I think what is happening is that, when you click on the column header, the grid column get sorted and the grid reloads. If the grid reloads, `doGridComplete` is called again. So add a `script` tag after the grid and call `doGridComplete();`. So you need to remove the `gridComplete`.

Comment: Still persisting .. I have added that `javascript doComplete()` in my `JSP` after that `grid code` . Still behaving like that only .. :(

Comment: @loser Remove the `onGridCompleteTopics="gridcomplete"` and `$.subscribe('gridcomplete', doGridComplete);` lines.

Comment: If I remove those lines . Sub columns are not getting created .. :( We are missing our main aim ..

Comment: You need to reload the grid after the changes for it to take effect. I forgot to tell you that. Please make sure you remove the `gridComplete` topic as per the previous comment. `$("#gridId").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', { useColSpanStyle: true, groupHeaders:[ {startColumnName: 'sub_Col1_name', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: '<em>col2 is main column</em>'}] }).trigger(“reloadGrid”);`

Comment: @looser Can you update your post with your present jsp?

Comment: Hey .. Somehow I managed to work it out .. But I dont know whats wrong in your code that I am doing .. I will Improve your answer with my new update can I impprove or edit your answer ?